# Why method name ends with 0?

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions

I recently find many methods' name in JDK that ends with "0", for example:

```
public class ObjectInputStream {
private Object readObject0(boolean unshared) throws IOException {

public class FileInputStream extends InputStream {
private native int read0() throws IOException;
```

Does anyone know what that's for?

Answer (score 2):

Probably to distinguish them from *public* methods called *readObject()*. That would be the one reasonable explanation that I can *guess*.

But the real answers are:

- you don't care: those are private methods. Thus they represent implementation details which do not matter to the outside world. Maybe the early java folks at Sun had their own internal conventions for such methods.
- you remember that those aren't good names, as they are not giving away what those methods are about. Their names might surprise people not working on the core java team.

So in essence: interesting finding - but should be seen as examples how to not do things.